# Is there a WebSocket client implemented for .NET?

Tags: .net, html, websocket, client

I would like to use WebSockets in my Windows Forms or WPF-application. Is there a .NET-control that is supporting WebSockets implemented yet? Or is there any open source project started about it?

An open source solution for a Java Client supporting WebSockets could also help me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Now, SuperWebSocket also includes a WebSocket client implementation
[SuperWebSocket Project Homepage](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)

Other .NET client implementations include:

- [Microsoft WebSocket client prototype](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info)
- [WebSocket-Sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)
- [Anaida](http://anaida.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I can't see to see anything in SuperWebSocket about a client implementation? Is it still there?

Comment: In SourceCode/mainline/Client

Comment: The client in SuperWebSocket has been separated into WebSocket4Net: http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: When I try to connect to socket.io from .NET using WebSocket4Net I see "debug - destroying non-socket.io upgrade". What am I missing?

Answer (score 24):

Here's a quick first pass at porting that Java code to C#. Doesn't support SSL mode and has only been very lightly tested, but it's a start.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class WebSocket
{
    private Uri mUrl;
    private TcpClient mClient;
    private NetworkStream mStream;
    private bool mHandshakeComplete;
    private Dictionary<string, string> mHeaders;
    
    public WebSocket(Uri url)
    {
        mUrl = url;
        
        string protocol = mUrl.Scheme;
        if (!protocol.Equals("ws") && !protocol.Equals("wss"))
            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported protocol: " + protocol);
    }
    
    public void SetHeaders(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        mHeaders = headers;
    }
    
    public void Connect()
    {
        string host = mUrl.DnsSafeHost;
        string path = mUrl.PathAndQuery;
        string origin = "http://" + host;

        mClient = CreateSocket(mUrl);
        mStream = mClient.GetStream();

        int port = ((IPEndPoint)mClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
        if (port != 80)
            host = host + ":" + port;

        StringBuilder extraHeaders = new StringBuilder();
        if (mHeaders != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in mHeaders)
                extraHeaders.Append(header.Key + ": " + header.Value + "\r\n");
        }

        string request = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                         "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" +
                         "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" +
                         "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
                         "Origin: " + origin + "\r\n" +
                         extraHeaders.ToString() + "\r\n";
        byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

        mStream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mStream);
        {
            string header = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!header.Equals("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake"))
                throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");

            header = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!header.Equals("Upgrade: WebSocket"))
                throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");

            header = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!header.Equals("Connection: Upgrade"))
                throw new IOException("Invalid handshake response");
        }

        mHandshakeComplete = true;
    }
    
    public void Send(string str)
    {
        if (!mHandshakeComplete)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Handshake not complete");

        byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

        mStream.WriteByte(0x00);
        mStream.Write(sendBuffer, 0, sendBuffer.Length);
        mStream.WriteByte(0xff);
        mStream.Flush();
    }

    public string Recv()
    {
        if (!mHandshakeComplete)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Handshake not complete");

        StringBuilder recvBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(mStream);
        byte b = reader.ReadByte();
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80)
        {
            // Skip data frame
            int len = 0;
            do
            {
                b = (byte)(reader.ReadByte() & 0x7f);
                len += b * 128;
            } while ((b & 0x80) != 0x80);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                reader.ReadByte();
        }
        
        while (true)
        {
            b = reader.ReadByte();
            if (b == 0xff)
                break;

            recvBuffer.Append(b);           
        }

        return recvBuffer.ToString();
    }
    
    public void Close()
    {
        mStream.Dispose();
        mClient.Close();
        mStream = null;
        mClient = null;
    }

    private static TcpClient CreateSocket(Uri url)
    {
        string scheme = url.Scheme;
        string host = url.DnsSafeHost;

        int port = url.Port;
        if (port <= 0)
        {
            if (scheme.Equals("wss"))
                port = 443;
            else if (scheme.Equals("ws"))
                port = 80;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported scheme");
        }

        if (scheme.Equals("wss"))
            throw new NotImplementedException("SSL support not implemented yet");
        else
            return new TcpClient(host, port);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that StringBuilder.Append(byte) doesn't do what you think it does -- it appends the textual representation of the byte to the buffer. Building a list of bytes and then converting that byte[] to a string using Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) works better.

Comment: +1 worked for me. I ended up modifying `mStream = new SslStream(mClient.GetStream());` and adding `mStream.AuthenicateAsClient(host);`, and that was all that was needed for SSL support.

Answer (score 12):

Support for WebSockets is [coming in .NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097383). That links also contains an example using the [System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: From the docs "the only public implementations of client and server WebSockets are supported on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012" - ie. it wont work with older versions of windows.

Answer (score 7):

Kaazing.com provide a .NET client library that can access websockets. They have tutorials online at [Checklist: Build Microsoft .NET JMS Clients](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/jms_client_docs/dev-dotnet/o_dev_dotnet.html) and [Checklist: Build Microsoft .NET AMQP Clients](https://kaazing.com/doc/5.0/amqp_client_docs/dev-dotnet/o_dev_dotnet.html)

There is a [Java Websocket Client](http://github.com/adamac/Java-WebSocket-client) project on github.

Answer (score 5):

There is a client implementation: http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/!

Answer (score 4):

another choice: [XSockets.Net](https://github.com/XSockets), has implement server and client.

can install server by:

```
PM> Install-Package XSockets
```

or install client by:

```
PM> Install-Package XSockets.Client
```

current version is: `3.0.4`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the list of .net supported websocket nuget packages

[Websocket pakages](http://nuget.org/packages?q=websocket).

I prefer following clients

1. [Alchemy websocket](http://nuget.org/packages/Alchemy/)
2. [SocketIO](http://nuget.org/packages/SocketIO4Net.Client/)

Answer (score 1):

it's a pretty simple protocol. there's a java implementation [here](http://github.com/adamac/Java-WebSocket-client/blob/master/src/com/sixfire/websocket/WebSocket.java) that shouldn't be too difficult to translate into c#. if i get around to doing it, i'll post it up here...

Answer (score 1):

Recently the Interoperability Bridges and Labs Center released a prototype implementation (in managed code) of two drafts of the WebSockets protocol specification:

*draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-75* and *draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76*

The prototype can be found at HTML5 Labs. I put in [this blog post](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2010/12/a-sneak-preview-of-websocket-enabled-wcf-services.html) all the information I found (until now) and snippets of code about how this can be done using WCF.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like something a little more lightweight, check out a C# server that a friend and I released: https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets

Supports vanilla websockets as well as flash websockets. It was built for our online game with a focus on scalability and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

There is also Alchemy. http://olivinelabs.com/Alchemy-Websockets/ which is rather cool.

Comment: and which is not a WebSocket client

Comment: Yes it is. There is a WebSocket client lib with it. Look again!

Comment: I don't see it as a lib actually. There is a [WebSocketClient class](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets/blob/master/src/Alchemy/WebSocketClient.cs) though, right