# Is there a WCF server implementation of Web Sockets form HTML 5?

Tags: .net, wcf, html, websocket

I would like to play with the new Web Socket support in Chrome (and soon Firefox), but have been unable to find a WCF implementation that will act as the server.

Have somebody implemented a .net WCF Web Socket based server?

Comment: I wrote the same (almost) question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064641/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-net

Comment: Sanoj: I did see your question, but as I read it you are asking for a client implementation, which I am not. I am asking for a server side implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The Web Socket [protocol specification](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-60.pdf) is so simple that you could implement a server to play with in a couple of hours. Assuming that you already have a TCP server component, it's just a matter of implementing the handshake (respond to a client request) and then receiving or sending data frames over TCP.

I used Delphi to implement the protocol and a chat server/client example; you can get the source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/delphiws/). It shouldn't be very hard to translate it to .NET.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion. I was actually considering just implementing it myself, but I try my best not to redo work already done. From the looks of it, I may have to actually do the work myself this time :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently the Interoperability Bridges and Labs Center released a prototype implementation (in managed code) of two drafts of the WebSockets protocol specification:

*draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-75* and *draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76*

The prototype can be found at HTML5 Labs. I put in [this blog post](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2010/12/a-sneak-preview-of-websocket-enabled-wcf-services.html) all the information I found (until now) and snippets of code about how this can be done using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution you may try this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebApp.aspx