# Is there a .NET Core socket-io client implementation?

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, socket.io

Is there a c# client that follows the socket.io protocol? I have an NodeJS application that runs a socket-io server and I need a client in another application in .Net Core that needs to communicate with the socket-io server.

These are some implementations that I've found:

[SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) - Deprecated

[socketio4net](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=socketio4net) - Deprecated

[IBM.Socket-IO](https://github.com/IBM/socket-io) - Doesn't Work in .NET Core

Is there anything more recent that is being maintained that can accomplish this task?

Comment: Have you looked at `SignalR`?

Comment: For what? The server is implemented with Socket-io, i can't connect a SignalR client to a Socket-io server.

Comment: Hi,@Ribeiro, I got the same question today and check the update please.

Comment: Any solution for socket io integration with .net core?

Answer (score 0):

**Update** 23/7

You can find all you needs from here [Communicating with a socket.io server via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499861/communicating-with-a-socket-io-server-via-c-sharp)

---

I think you might need this socket.io implementation in asp.net core

https://github.com/Beffyman/SocketIo.Core

Comment: Which one did you ended up using?

Comment: I tested Websocket both server on node.js and client on .net. It works on me. You could check here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035593/clientwebsocket-socketexception-no-connection-could-be-made/63049364#63049364. Sorry for no implementation of  Socket.io.

Comment: You linked to an answer that is nearly 10 years old.