# ClientWebSocket - SocketException: No connection could be made

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, websocket

I am trying to connect to WebSocket server (demo or localhost) using ClientWebSocket.
I get an exception:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
  Source=System.Net.WebSockets.Client
  StackTrace:

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I also have JavaScript websocket client which connected succefully. Why I can't connect using ClientWebSocket?

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StreamJsonRpc;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to end.");
                //await ConnectAsync("ws://localhost:63762/ws");
                await ConnectAsync("ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(ex);
                  Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static async Task ConnectAsync(string url)
        {
            using (var socket = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("---> JSON-RPC Client connecting to " + url);

                await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None);
                Console.WriteLine("-> Connected to web socket. Establishing JSON-RPC protocol...");
                                                         
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: await ConnectAsync("ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo"); The url is the main reason failed to connect. Change other ws server to test. https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: It works when I test your code with other ws server.

Comment: I write simple WebSocket server in nodejs to test connection on localhost. My websocket web client connected successfully but console app failed to connect every time.

Comment: I already updated my codes and it works on me, could u check the difference？

Comment: Update to .Net Core 3.1 solved my problem.

Comment: Ok, that's why it works on me. My runtime is  .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 24/07**

> I write simple WebSocket server in nodejs to test connection on
> localhost. My websocket web client connected successfully but console
> app failed to connect every time.

If so, it doesn't make sense. It works on me.
[image]

There are codes of `ws` client in .net `console application`.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to end.");
            await ConnectAsync("ws://localhost:8080");
            //await ConnectAsync("ws://demos.kaazing.com/echo");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // This is the normal way we close.
        }

    }

    static async Task ConnectAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var socket = new ClientWebSocket())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---> JSON-RPC Client connecting to " + url);

            await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None);
            Console.WriteLine("-> Connected to web socket. Establishing JSON-RPC protocol...");


            await Send(socket, "Hello from client.");
            await Receive(socket);

            await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "close", CancellationToken.None);

        }

    }

    static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket socket, string data) =>
await socket.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);


    static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket socket)
    {
        var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[2048]);
        do
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                do
                {
                    result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                    ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
                } while (!result.EndOfMessage);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    break;

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                    Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
        } while (true);
    }
```

There are ws codes of my `node.js` server with websocket.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 })

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log(`Received message => ${message}`)
  })
  ws.send('Hello from server!')
})

console.log('Server running at ws://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

_______________________________________________________________

`ClientWebSocket` can not directly connect to `socket.io` in Python.

**Here is a solution from** @Jim Stott.
There is a project on [CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=socketio4net) ( [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/SocketIO4Net.Client) as well ) that is a `C#` client for `socket.io`.

Example client style:

```
socket.On("news", (data) =>    {
Console.WriteLine(data);
});
```

And also there are many ways to meet your needs from the question below.
**[Communicating with a socket.io server via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499861/communicating-with-a-socket-io-server-via-c-sharp)**

Here is the article about **[WebSocket vs Socket.io](https://www.educba.com/websocket-vs-socket-io/)**

Comment: But I don't want to install socket.io. I'd like to connect to websocket server using System.Net.WebSockets.

Comment: Sorry, I thought u r using socket.io to build ws server before.

Comment: Ok. I thought so code should work. Thanks for you effort. I will keep looking solution.

Comment: If it's not associated with codes, you might check the firewall or OS version( Win 8 Later). Hope u get the right answer. :)