# I want to implement client-side web socket connection in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket, socket.io, websocket-sharp

Javascript code is working for this:

```
function testSocket()
{  
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3001/",{
      query:{Token:"YWRtaW5Ac3RsdGVjaC5pbjpzdGxAMTIzOjE2MTEzNDE3OTk1OTY="}, 
    });
    socket.on('message-processed',(event,callback)=>{
      writeToScreen(event);
    });
}
```

but I need to implement this in C#. I tried the code shown below, but it is not  working:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/Token=YWRtaW5Ac3RsdGVjaC5pbjpz=");
                
ws.Connect();
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        Console.WriteLine("Laputa says: " + e.Data);

ws.Send("message-processed");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Also consider SignalR if your JavaScript side is not fixed in its implementation

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3). I'll reference the documentation here:

> Socket.IO **is NOT a WebSocket implementation**. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why **a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server**, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain WebSocket server either.

Needless to say `websocket-sharp` IS a websocket client implementation. Be that as it may, not all hope is lost:

I don't want to c/p the answers, so please find alternative client libraries here: [Communicating with a socket.io server via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499861/communicating-with-a-socket-io-server-via-c-sharp)

Comment: code is available for .net but i am using .net core

Comment: https://github.com/Beffyman/SocketIo.Core try this one.

Comment: You must be a bit more specific for me to help.

Comment: I just need to implement client side socket connections from my asp.net core project ,server side code of socket  is written in node js,unable to find solution.

Comment: Not working might mean anything. You have to narrow down what's happening.