# Integrate a C# client into a node.js + socket.io chat app

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js

As part of learning node.js, I just created a very basic chat server with node.js and socket.io. The server basically adds everyone who visits the chat.html wep page into a real time chat and everything seems to be working!

Now, I'd like to have a C# desktop application take part in the chat (without using a web browser control :)).

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: [C# websocket clients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064641/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-net/5257096#5257096). The more optimum solution would be to expose a TCP socket through socket.io, but that sounds like a right pain to do.

Answer (score 4):

I created a socket server in nodejs, and connected to it using TcpClient.

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(serverIp, port));
    using (var w = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream()))
        w.Write("Here comes the message");
}
```

Comment: It could be a little more complete, eg. Explaining how you send and get socket.io messages, but this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.  It is pretty easy to use and doesn't have any dependencies on things like System.Web or any specific web browser.  I use it simulating browser requests and analyzing responses in testing applications.  It is flexible enough to allow you to set your own per request headers (in case you are working with a restful service, or some other service with expectations of specific headers).  Additionally, it will follow redirects for you by default, but this behavior easy to turn off.

Creating a new request is simple:

```
HttpWebRequest my_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://some.url/and/resource");
```

To submit the request:

```
HttpWebResponse my_response = my_request.GetResponse();
```

Now you can make sure you got the right status code, look at response headers, and you have access to the response body through a stream object.  In order to do things like add post data (like HTML form data) to the request, you just write a UTF8 encoded string to the request object's stream.

This library should be pretty easy to include into any WinForms or WPF application.  The docs on MSDN are pretty good.

One gotcha though, if the response isn't in the 200-402 range, HttpWebRequest throws an exception that you have to catch.  Fortunately you can still access the response object, but it is kind of annoying that you have to handle it as an exception (especially since the exception is on the server side and not in your client code).

Comment: Http is not designed for bi-directional communications like in socket.io, to use it you should implement long polling, if you are on .Net it makes much more sense to just use Tcp Sockets.