# Can not accept socket connections on server

Tags: sockets, .net-core

I have created a `.NET Console App` in which i want to accept `client` websockets.(I am using the chrome extension -`Simple Web Socket Client`).
When i try to send messages to the connected clients i get this error in the browser :

```
    WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8600/' failed: 
    Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
    CLOSED: ws://localhost:8600
```

**Server**

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Console.WriteLine("starting server...");
            Task server = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                var point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8600);

                serverSocket.Bind(point);
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on localhost:8600" );
                serverSocket.Listen(6);
                var client = await serverSocket.AcceptAsync();
                Task clientTask = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await client.SendAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Date is" + DateTime.Now.ToString()), SocketFlags.None);
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                    }
                },src.Token);

            }, src.Token);
            while (true)
            {
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.A)
                {
                    src.Cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

From Simple Web Socket Client ( chrome extension) i try to connect to :
`ws://localhost:8600`

**P.S** I am not sure about passing the same token in all tasks , but besides this i do not know why it keeps with this error.

Answer (score 2):

### Your server code is not implementing the [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) or [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) protocols at all.

A WebSocket session begins life as an [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) session, where the client sends an [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) request asking the server to upgrade the connection to the [WebSocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), and the server's [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) response then indicates whether that upgrade was successful or not, before any WebSocket messages can then be exchanged.

Your server is just opening a plain ordinary TCP port and then sending arbitrary string data as soon as the client connects.  You are not following the [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) or [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) protocols at all.  So, of course, a WebSocket client will report a failure to establish a WebSocket session.  Your server is not sending back a valid HTTP upgrade response (just as the client error says).

Instead of using the [`Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket) class directly, try using the [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener) and [`HttpListenerWebSocketContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.httplistenerwebsocketcontext) classes instead.  For example:

[How to work with System.Net.WebSockets without ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490140/)