# Connection to socket gets error "WebSocket opening handshake timed out" using Javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sockets, websocket

About 4 hours of research...here we go.

I have a C# program that sends and listens for anything coming in a specific Socket. Using the sockets, C# can send stuff to it and can receive from it just fine. Now, going to my JavaScript file, I'm using the WebSocket interface to communicate with C#, but doesn't work (usually times out after a couple of minutes).  When the Socket is online, the JavaScript code will take up to about 4 minutes then throw an error saying "WebSocket opening handshake timed out".  The thing is I know that it can find because, when the port of the ip doesn't exist the JavaScript file throws an error in the next couple seconds.

Things I've done:

Turn off all firewalls, use both ws and wss at the beginning of the ip and port (ex: wss://xxx.xxx.x.xx:11111), change the port, change the ip to a valid ip still reachable, research for 4 hours.

C#:

```
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("ip");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11111);

Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

try
{
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint);

    listener.Listen(10);

    while (true)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting connection...");

        Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();

        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        string data = null;

        while (true)
        {

            int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);

            data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numByte);

            if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Text received -> {0} ", data);
        byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Server");

        clientSocket.Send(message);

        clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

JavaScript:

```
socket = new WebSocket("wss://ip:11111");
socket.onopen = function()
{
    alert("Connected!");
}
socket.onerror = function()
{
    alert("Connection Failed");
}
```

The ip is local

Long story short, C# can communicate with itself and JavaScript can find it but can't communicate with it.

Comment: Ok, but as I said, I have used ws.  Also, I dont know how to get the `Connection: Upgrade

GET ws://websocket.example.com/ HTTP/1.1

Origin: http://example.comConnection: Upgrade

Connection: Upgrade

Host: websocket.example.comConnection: Upgrade

Upgrade: websocket`

Comment: I’ve no doubt that WS has been used with a server that *correctly implements* handshaking/accepting an incoming  WS request. The code above does not - as it fails to adhere to the defined protocol - and is not expected to work.

Comment: I highly suggest using `System.Net.HttpListener` which can set up a `System.Net.Websocket` connection for you via the `HttpListenerContext` / `HttpListenerRequest `.

Comment: Ok.  I'll work on that right now.  I'll get back as soon as I figure it out or otherwise.

Comment: In fact, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896157/15880) tells you how to use `HttpListener` to set things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly *complete* a handshake. (Or use a library / connection type that does.)

The WebSocket protocol (as original defined in [RFC6455 - The WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)) does *not* open a plain unrestricted socket, in part for security reasons.

Since the handshake is not complete, the client WS request will timeout as the HTTP “Upgrade” response is never received. *Until the handshake is complete, the WS will not be active over the underlying TCP connection.*

Initiating a WebSocket connection (“the handshake”) is defined in [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4) of the RFC. It is also discussed in [How JavaScript works: Deep dive into WebSockets and HTTP/2 with SSE + how to pick the right path](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-deep-dive-into-websockets-and-http-2-with-sse-how-to-pick-the-right-path-584e6b8e3bf7).

> The client establishes a WebSocket connection through a process known as the WebSocket handshake. This process starts with the client sending a regular HTTP request to the server. An Upgrade header is included in this request which informs the server that the client wishes to establish a WebSocket connection.
>
> ..
>
> Now that *[after] the handshake is complete the initial HTTP connection is replaced by a WebSocket connection* that uses the same underlying TCP/IP connection. At this point, either party can start sending data.

Comment: I have no idea where the `GET ws://websocket.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://example.com
Connection: Upgrade
Host: websocket.example.com
Upgrade: websocket` goes.  And do I properly complete the handshake in C# or JavaScript?

Comment: The JS side is correct, as implemented by the browser and the WebSocket type (which properly sends the initial handshake and waits for the connection to be upgraded). The C# side is incorrect as it never completes the required handshake.

Comment: Either write a (minimally) valid implementation (see the RFC, etc. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) or use an existing valid library that understands how to accept a WS handshake/connection. A minimally valid implementation might simply return the required HTTP and “Upgrade” headers.

Comment: Specifically, Section 4.2 of RFC6455 - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-4.2

Comment: Looks like the HttpListener worked.  Thank you so freaking much.